# Bootstrap drop down not working in Angular . Why?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use simple bootstrap 3 drop down in Angular 5 project. But it is not working i.e when i am clicking on the dropdown, dropdown list is not coming up. I am getting no error on console. Is there any specific reason for it not to work. Please help

Different version which i am using :

Bootstrap 3
Angular 5

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li ><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">ENQUIRY</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">COMPLAINTS AND GRIEVANCES</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: be more specific than "it doesn't work" that is not very helpful; what doesnt work/post image result.

Comment: How are you including the bootstrap library? Bootstrap's dropdown component relies on some of the bootstrap javascript -- for Bootstrap 3 it relies on dropdown.js and for 4 it relies on popper.js.

Comment: Please post your index.html or .angular-cli.json file how did you include the bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery Library to the header section of the index.html file.

Like: 
`<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>`